# Cannot get Facebook like button code for my webpages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have been adding facebook like button code on all the pages of my website www.fitgunler.com since a year. For the last 2 weeks, I cannot seem to get a code for the like button. As I have always done before, I go to the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ page, enter my URL and click get code. However first "Not logged in, please log in to continue" box appears, then I click log in (by the way I am already logged in on another tab while I am doing this) and then it goes to the same initial page, I enter the URL and click get code and again the same login box appears.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Are you sure you're logged in? Can you see your facebook-profile at the top of that page to generate the code? It seems that your session cannot be created.

You should not be logged in on another tab to be sure that facebook does not confuse with two logins.

Comment: Hello,
I don't think that is the problem. I tried once again after reading your reply, facebook is open only on one tab - which is my personal profile. I go straight down to the bottom of the page and click the Developers and find the like button page from there, and again the same problem.

The problem is, when I click the Developers at the bottom of my profile homepage, on the page that opens, it shows "Log In" at the right top end, like I am not logged in. I click that, and nothing happens! it just refreshes the same developers main page....